# Android: найти значение в Sqlite

Tags: search, android, sqlite

Здравствуйте.
Я только начинаю учиться программированию, перерыл кучу примеров и уроков, но дело не продвигается.
Есть android приложение, есть Sqlite база.
Есть `SQliteOpenHelper`:

```
package com.network.CableDiag.dbhelper;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class ExternalDbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //Путь к папке с базами на устройстве
    public static String DB_PATH;
    //Имя файла с базой
    public static String DB_NAME;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    public final Context context;

    public SQLiteDatabase getDb() {
        return database;
    }

    public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context, String databaseName) {
        super(context, databaseName, null, 1);
        this.context = context;
        //Составим полный путь к базам для вашего приложения
        String packageName = context.getPackageName();
        DB_PATH = String.format("//data//data//%s//databases//", packageName);
        DB_NAME = databaseName;
        openDataBase();
    }

    //Создаст базу, если она не создана
    public void createDataBase() {
        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Copying error");
                throw new Error("Error copying database!");
            }
        } else {
            Log.i(this.getClass().toString(), "Database already exists");
        }
    }
    //Проверка существования базы данных
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDb = null;
        try {
            String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDb = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "Error while checking db");
        }
        //Андроид не любит утечки ресурсов, все должно закрываться
        if (checkDb != null) {
            checkDb.close();
        }
        return checkDb != null;
    }
    //Метод копирования базы
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
        // Открываем поток для чтения из уже созданной нами БД
        //источник в assets
        InputStream externalDbStream = context.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Путь к уже созданной пустой базе в андроиде
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Теперь создадим поток для записи в эту БД побайтно
        OutputStream localDbStream = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // Собственно, копирование
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesRead;
        while ((bytesRead = externalDbStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            localDbStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        // Закроем потоки
        localDbStream.close();
        externalDbStream.close();

    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        String path = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        if (database == null) {
            createDataBase();
            database = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(path, null,
                    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        }
        return database;
    }
    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (database != null) {
            database.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {}
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
}
```

Как мне произвести поиск в базе (база содержит имя и адрес, поиск нужно производить только по адресу и выводить имя+адрес)?

Comment: я думаю, стоит вначале изучить основы SQL, потом специфику работы с SQLite, дальше Android SQLite Database.

Answer (score 2):

Непонятно какая у вас схема БД. А так для поиска используйте метод

```
SQLiteDatabase.query(...)
```

В чистом SQL все просто

```
 SELECT name, address FROM table WHERE address = ''
```